# UIScrollView of buttons - TouchUpInside?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, drag

I have a UIScrollView filled with buttons that I created programatically.
Paging is enabled and whenever users scroll through the pages rapidly they always end up accidentally clicking buttons that they didn't mean to... Should I be using TouchUpInside or is this the reason for my problem?

One thing I've noticed is that if a user presses the button then slides the scrollview doesn't move but if they slide the scroll view very quickly and let go half way through the scroll and they grabbed the scrollview on the button then the button will become "pressed" is there any way I can have the buttons not do anything if they are clicked while scrolling is in progress or is the solution simpler than that (i.e. just changing the touch event to a different listener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick!

```
setExclusiveTouch:YES
```

Comment: ^*Note I also used TouchUpInside with this, that may also be contributing to the effect that resulted!